# Flink DataStream[String] kafkaconsumer convert to Avro for Sink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

**FLINK Streaming:** I have DataStream[String] from kafkaconsumer which is
JSON

```
stream = env
    .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))
```

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html

I have to sink this stream using StreamingFileSink, which needs DataStream[GenericRecord]

```
val schema: Schema = ...
val input: DataStream[GenericRecord] = ...
val sink: StreamingFileSink[GenericRecord] = StreamingFileSink
    .forBulkFormat(outputBasePath, AvroWriters.forGenericRecord(schema))
    .build()
input.addSink(sink)
```

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html

**Question:** How to convert DataStream[String] to DataStream[GenericRecord] before Sinking so that I can write AVRO files ?

Exception while converting String stream to generic data strem

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:408)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$flink$api$scala$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:400)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:168)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment.scalaClean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.scala:791)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream.clean(DataStream.scala:1168)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream.map(DataStream.scala:617)
    at com.att.vdcs.StreamingJobKafkaFlink$.main(StreamingJobKafkaFlink.scala:128)
    at com.att.vdcs.StreamingJobKafkaFlink.main(StreamingJobKafkaFlink.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:586)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:406)
    ... 7 more
```

After initializing schema in mapper, Getting cast exception.

```
org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple2 cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

schema and msg below in screen:
[image: schema and msg in screen below]

Got through CAST Exception by casting like:

```
record.put(0,scala.collection.JavaConverters.mapAsJavaMapConverter(msg._1).asJava)
```

Now streaming is working good Except there are extra Escape Characters added

```
,"body":"\"{\\\"hdr\\\":{\\\"mes
```

there are extra escape \

it should be like:

```
,"body":"\"{\"hdr\":{\"mes
```

extra escape was removed after changing toString to getAsString

Now its working as expected.

Need to try SNAPPY compression of stream next.

Comment: What kind of String data are You reading ? Is it JSON ??

Comment: @Dominik. Yes it is JSON string

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your stream of Strings into a stream of GenericRecords, for example using a `.map()` function.

**Example:**

```
DataStream<String> strings = env.addSource( ... );
DataStream<GenericRecord> records = strings.map(inputStr -> {
    GenericData.Record rec = new GenericData.Record(schema);
    rec.put(0, inputStr);
    return rec;
});
```

Please note that using `GenericRecord` can lead to a poor performance, because the schema needs to be serialized with each record over and over again.
It is better to generate an Avro Pojo, as it won't need to ship the schema.

Comment: Robert. I tried that option few times. But I am getting Error "org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: Task not serializable" at converting stream to generic record

Comment: Can you provide me with the full exception stack trace?

Comment: Added at bottom of above main description. I was not sure how to add it here in comment section.

Comment: The problem is that the `schema` is not serializable. In the `main()` method, Flink is only assembling a dataflow representation, that is send to the cluster. As part of this cluster sending process, all code needs to be serialized. Since the Avro schema is not serializable, you can not pass it into the lambda. Potential solutions: a) initialize the schema inside the mapper b) use Avro POJOs (recommended)

Comment: thanks Robert. Added another cast exception in main description above, Could you please suggest solution for that.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your help.. Its good for now. Updated description above,

Comment: @RobertMetzger Reg your GenericRecord performance note, is it stated explicitly in Flink Avro docs somewhere? If yes, could you please point me to the doc link? I was in assumption that both are same in terms of performance

Answer (score 0):

In java, you should use a RichMapFunction to convert DataStream to DataStream and add a transient Schema field to generate GenericRecord. But i dont know how to do this in scala, just for reference.

```
DataStream<GenericRecord> records = maps.map(new RichMapFunction<Map<String, Object>, GenericRecord>() {
        private transient DatumWriter<IndexedRecord> datumWriter;

        /**
         * Output stream to serialize records into byte array.
         */
        private transient ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOutputStream;

        /**
         * Low-level class for serialization of Avro values.
         */
        private transient Encoder encoder;
        /**
         * Avro serialization schema.
         */
        private transient Schema schema;
        @Override
        public GenericRecord map(Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap) throws Exception {
            GenericRecord record =  new GenericData.Record(schema);
            stringObjectMap.entrySet().forEach(entry->{record.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());});
            return record;
        }


        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            super.open(parameters);
            this.arrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            this.encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(arrayOutputStream, null);
            this.datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
            try {
                this.schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(avroSchemaString);
            } catch (SchemaParseException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse Avro schema string.", e);
            }
        }
    });

    final StreamingFileSink<GenericRecord> sink = StreamingFileSink
            .forBulkFormat(new Path("D:\\test"), AvroWriters.forGenericRecord(mongoSchema))
            .build();
    records.addSink(sink);
```